# I'd like to run a few terminal commands from inside vim

Tags: terminal, vim, gnome, firefox, node.js

There are two common things I do when I code something. I either open that file in the browser or run it in node. So I'd like to create a couple of shortcuts inside vim to that effect.

I'd like <kbd>F5</kbd> to open a new gnome terminal in the current directory and run `http-server` and then open up a new tab in firefox hitting port 8000.

Also, I'd like <kbd>F6</kbd> to open a new gnome terminal and run `nodemon` and then open a new firefox tab and hit port 8000.

```
nnoremap <F5> :exe ':silent !firefox %'
nnoremap <F5> :exe ':silent !firefox %'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be better suited to the vi/vim stack over at vi.stackexchange.com

Note that the :silent tag negates hitting enter, so that has to be added after the set of commands to make it run in the command line.  I had quite a bit of luck with the following.

```
:nnoremap <F5> :exe ':silent !firefox % 2>/dev/null &'^M^L
```

Please note that you have to hit ctrl-V to get the ctrl-M and ctrl-L bits at the end. Here is a quick rundown of what I added.

```
2>/dev/null to avoid dumping stderr to screen.
& to allow us to drop back to vim without waiting for firefox to finish
^M to execute the command
^L to initiate a redraw (the command frequently blacked out my screen)
```

Weirdly enough, without the stderr redirect, I just had to wait until firefox finished dumping errors to the screen and redraw again.  Much easier to just trash those lines before they can display weird bits.

Comment: Here's what I ended up using: `nnoremap <F5> :!gnome-terminal -e http-server <CR> :silent !firefox thinkmachine:8080<CR> <C-l>
` Worked really nicely. Just have to alt-tab-tab to get back.